# How to load a Java BufferedImage into Matlab

Tags: java, image, matlab, bufferedimage

I'm trying to call some Java methods from MATLAB and have been successful with those that return things like Strings, Files etc. But now I have a method that returns a `BufferedImage`, which MATLAB doesn't have a problem with YET. But how does one visualize this `BufferedImage` in MATLAB ? Or at least convert it into a matrix?

I called the following method (which is in my Java class) from MATLAB :

MATLAB code:

```
bufferedImage = pictureObject.getBufferedImage
```

MATLAB shows this...

> `pictureObject =`
>
> `BufferedImage@9d7ae3: type = 13 IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@eee0e3 transparency = 1 transIndex   = -1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 640 height = 480 #numDataElements 1 dataOff[0] = 0`

And I'm trying to convert the above thing into something visualizable in MATLAB .

Comment: Did my answer get you what you needed?

Answer (score 3):

For a Java `BufferedImage` called `jbi`, you can use `getData` and `getPixels` to get a MATLAB array.

Create a test `BufferedImage` with [`im2java2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2java2d.html) (too bad there is no `java2d2im`):

```
>> I = imread('cameraman.tif');
>> jbi = im2java2d(I)
jbi =
BufferedImage@7ed666f9: type = 0 IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numCompon<snip>
```

Convert back:

```
nrows = jbi.getHeight; ncols = jbi.getWidth;
matImg = jbi.getData.getPixels(0,0,ncols,nrows,[]);
matImg = uint8(reshape(matImg,nrows,ncols)');
```

The above works for the grayscale "cameraman.tif" image (`pixelBits = 8`).

---

For the color "peppers.png" image (`pixelBits = 24`):

```
data = jbi.getData.getPixels(0,0,ncols,nrows,[]);
matImg = permute(reshape(data,3,ncols,nrows),[3 2 1]);
```

Or

```
data = reshape(typecast(jbi.getData.getDataStorage, 'uint8'), [], ncols, nrows);
matImg = permute(data,[3 2 1]);
```

See [this MathWorks answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100155) for more tricks.

Comment: it gave me error : Java exception occurred:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

 at java.awt.image.SampleModel.getPixels(Unknown Source)

 at java.awt.image.Raster.getPixels(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedImage` is not a primitive Java object that Matlab understands and there is no simple method to convert it to a matlab array. You should either

1. visualize using Java GUI (awt),
2. create a 3D array of the same size in Matlab and copy all pixels one by one in a loop, or
3. save your image into a file that Matlab understands (e.g., `png`) and load it from Matlab.